# Tips for Bleeding Hayes Brakes

Tags: mountain-bike, hydraulic-disc-brake, hayes

Does anyone have any tips for bleeding Hayes brakes? I have some Hayes Stroker Ryders and bleeding them is less than fun compared to bleeding my Avids.  Do they make any syringes for bleeding the Hayes? I've watched videos put out by Hayes and read their documentation, so I'm looking for tips that you would learn from experience.

Comment: See http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/130/hydraulic-disc-brakes-maintenance/365#365

Comment: this is different. Kristof needs to realign the pads around the rotor - and I said that as an answer. the other response is a link to a document put out by hayes. I am looking for advice that you wouldn't find in a document put out by the mfg.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing out something I found - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpdTKzgoVGk. my apologies if this missed the mark.

Comment: Could you describe the process in your own words in addition the link to the video?