# My hydraulic Hayes brake lever comes down and clicks, and it doesn’t retract?

Tags: brake-levers

My Hayes “Purple” hydraulic brake lever doesn’t work. I thought the reservoir was empty, so I put some brake fluid in and it didn’t work. The lever comes down too far with no response to the brakes, then sorta clicks. What should I do? Any suggestions would help a lot because I am going biking soon.

Comment: Is there any resistance when you pull the lever back?

Comment: No, not at all. It is extremely easy to pull it down

Comment: Probably need bleeding ... have a look at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/716/tips-for-bleeding-hayes-brakes

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Either the mechanical linkage to the piston is broken - which would explain the lack of return force, but if the lever is not loose and appears to be pushing the piston then the problem is in the hydraulic system.

The lever not returning indicates you have a bigger problem than just needing a bleed. If you lost substantial amount of hydraulic fluid you should be able to see a leak.

I think you have no option but to take it to a good bike mechanic for diagnosis and repair, or replacement.